# CSS - custom cursor looks terrible in Firefox

Tags: css

I am having a hard time with making Firefox to display my custom cursor the way I want. It work's like a charm in Chrome (not at all in IE...), but in Firefox it looks like really bad gif image. Have to be said, that it's transparent .cur. I will be glad for any help.

Chrome: [image]
Firefox: [image]

Here is a CSS code for it:

```
#productImg TD IMG:hover {cursor: url('images/cursor.cur') 16 16, auto;}
```

Comment: "but in Firefox it looks like really bad gif image." -- perhaps because it _is_ a really bad gif image? JK. It seems that firefox does not support semi-transparent cursors

Comment: Can we get the cursor file?

Comment: Sure: http://files.uloziste.com/1ba34550434fde26/cursor.cur

Comment: Ok, so I dumped the .cur way and used png directly... works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this isn't an answer but I don't have sufficient kudos to post to the comments section.  Could you show what CSS you used to get the .png to work and also your file structure (i.e. is the file relative to the .css file or the source element?).  I can't get either a .cur or a .png to work in FF although they work fine in other browsers.  I've been following the advice in this post which seems fine for other browsers except FF.

http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2008/01/08/cross-browser-custom-css-cursors/

FYI I'm trying to apply this to the BODY tag (not that this should matter).  FF recognises the CSS in both Firebug and the Inspector although the Inspector reports that the value is Auto.  When I manually set the property to a test Div/Class, FF just drops the property.  Current code below.

cursor: url(img/cursors/tinyGreen.cur), url(../img/cursors/tinyGreen.png), url(../img/cursors/tinyGreen.cur), default;

Comment: Ok, so it seems that once I pushed the code to the server, everyone gets the correct cursor except me.  As such I can only assume that this is something OS-specific to me (we're all Windows but probably some poxy Registry setting).  Have decided to retire to a convent to nurse my aching head ;-)